# Finding all possible paths in a directed, (possibly) cyclic graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I need to find all possible paths in a directed graph, that may have loops. The graph has a defined start and one or multiple defined endings. Basically im trying to find all possible scenarios in a Use Case Description. Since loops may occur, the user may define how many times a loop/alternative flow may be repeated. [image]

For this example and a cycle depth of 1 the possible scenarios should be:

S1: $1 \to 2 \to 3 \to 5$

S2: $1 \to 2 \to 4$

S3: $1 \to 2 \to 3 \to 2 \to 3 \to 5$

S4: $1 \to 2 \to 3 \to 2 \to 4$

So far i tried saving which edges I've visited but then i might get stuck in the middle of the graph when a loop occurs. Anyone got an idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: Use a modified DFS in which instead of recording *whether* you have visited each vertex, you record the number of times you have visited it, and visit it only if it is below the given threshold.  Note that there could be an exponential number of paths *even if there are no cycles* (consider a "ladder" graph with 2 rows and $n$ columns, and all 4 possible forward edges between the  2 vertices in column $i$ to the 2 vertices in column $i+1$).